# Displaying the user input on browser using googleappengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I am trying to run a web app on browser using `googleappengine`. My codes are below. What I wanna do is just whatever input is given through html, it should be received at servlet and display on browser again.

```
public class TestServerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

        try{


        String name= req.getParameter("name");
        String msg = req.getParameter("message");


            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("user name is"+name);


        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }


    }

}
```

**index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Submission Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<from method="POST" action ="TestServer">
Mail id: <input type ="text" name ="name"/><br/>
Message: <input type ="text" name ="message"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</from>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestServer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.test.TestServerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestServer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/testserver</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

So, when I run on browser with `http://localhost:8088/index.html` , the html form is shown, but I am unable to view the output. Can someone please suggest me where I am going wrong?

Comment: what happens if you change `resp.setContentType("text/plain");` to `resp.setContentType("text/html");`?

Comment: @ZackMacomber No change. The form doesn't move at all. It just stays as it is though I submit.

Comment: `<from method="POST" action ="TestServer">` needs to be changed to `<form method="POST" action ="TestServer">` ("form" instead of "from")

Comment: @ZackMacomber: Good eye! I also think the action should be changed to "/testserver".

Comment: @ZackMacomber Thanks. My bad. Now I am able to see that it redirects to servlet class. But I don't get anything on the browser which I am printing still :(